# iOS rotate view around an anchor point and follow touch

Tags: ios

I need to create a circular rating meter in iOS, it's like a UISlider only curved 3/4 around a circle. I need to rotate a UIImageView (which is the rating needle) around an anchor point, by dragging an invisible touchable handle area the will follow the tip of the needle. The angle of the needle will determine a value.

I am struggling to find an elegant solution. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using the `anchorPoint` property of the `UIImageView`'s underlying layer? If you have a `CGPoint` representing the point (in your image view's coords) around which it is to rotate, you can set the layer's anchor point:

```
CGRect imageBounds = self.needleImageView.bounds;
[self.needleImageView.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(rotationPoint.x / imageBounds.size.width, rotationPoint.y / imageBounds.size.height)];
```

Ensure that the image view's `center` property is set to the appropriate position also, and then apply the rotation transform to rotate about the layer's anchor point:

```
self.needleImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.needleImageView.transform, angleInRadians);
```

Remember that you need to import `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in order to access the layer's properties.

Comment: How could I go about getting the needle to point towards the touch position and then follow along as the touch position drags? I fear it might be time to bust out ye olde trigonometry.

Comment: @jmcopeland: Yep, trig sounds good to me (well... you know what I mean). You know the x and y translation from the rotation point so the finding the angle should be trivial. Just be aware that you may need to account for the fact that the rotation will work from -π to +π, rather than 0 to 2π. Also, I like to avoid using `tan(x) = opp/adj` in case of divide-by-zero errors.

Comment: Hi Stuart, I am stuck in a simmilar problem you solved above, can you please chat